# Как добавить класс к button при наведении и клике по нему

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру, мы имеем `<button class="button">Hello</button>`, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на кнопку, добавлялся/удалялся класс `button-hover`, а при клике по кнопке (Правой/Левой кнопкою мыши), добавлялся класс `button-click` и сразу-же удалялся, как только кликнули по кнопке. Я знаю, что подобное можно сделать через css (`:hover/:active`), но нужно именно через js. Заранее благодарю, кто поможет с данным вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

[пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crqajw2e/)

```
    'use strict';

  let btn = document.querySelector('.button');
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    event.target.classList.add('button-hover')
  });

  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
    event.target.classList.remove('button-hover')
  });

  btn.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    event.target.classList.add('button-click')
  })

  btn.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    event.target.classList.remove('button-click')
  })
```